# Seeking API to check OpenStreetMap for village boundaries?

Tags: openstreetmap, software-recommendations, api, administrative-boundaries

I am new to GIS programming and I have started a little project.

I have a lot of gpx tracks, and I want to check which villages i have visited.

Is there an API to check OpenStreetMap for village boundaries?

I would like to get those village boundaries as polygons, because it is easy to check if a track goes through polygons using Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell us first how you want to determine each village boundary polygon from OSM data:

By name, by OSM object ID number, by a center coordinate?

Try https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/ first to get an overview about available boundary polygons inside the OSM database, try the tree menu on the left there, or the search box on upper right corner.

Comment: I downloaded a dataset in geojson: admin_level  8 is the boundaries i want to check againsts. I think this data is exactly what i need.
With `shape` from the python lib `shapely.geometry` i can check with `shape.intersects` if 2 polygons intersect.